# Laravel 5.4 and Axion making me crazy: "Axios is not defined"

Tags: node.js, laravel-5, axios, laravel-passport

I'm running Laravel 5.4 with Vue.js and Axios with Laravel Passport. So in my /home I call Vue.js components:

```
<passport-clients></passport-clients>
<passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
<passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
```

When I run the server and got into page, the components are loaded. However, the action buttons doesn't work and this error's appears:

> vue.js?3de6:482 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: axios is not defined" found in --->  at /home/someusername/Documentos/AGIL/DESENVOLVIMENTO/somefolder/projeto/resources/assets/js/components/passport/Clients.vue

And other's, such as:

> ReferenceError: axios is not defined
>       at VueComponent.getClients (eval at  (app.js:320), :277:13)
>       at VueComponent.boundFn [as getClients] (eval at  (app.js:418), :186:12)
>       at VueComponent.prepareComponent (eval at  (app.js:320), :260:18)
>       at VueComponent.boundFn [as prepareComponent] (eval at  (app.js:418), :186:12)
>       at VueComponent.mounted (eval at  (app.js:320), :252:14)
>       at callHook (eval at  (app.js:418), :2705:21)
>       at Object.insert (eval at  (app.js:418), :3586:7)
>       at invokeInsertHook (eval at  (app.js:418), :5532:28)
>       at Vue$3.patch [as **patch**] (eval at  (app.js:418), :5735:5)
>       at Vue$3.Vue._update (eval at  (app.js:418), :2454:19)

This is making me crazy, I already installed Axios, Vue.js, any tip?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple:

Number one: if you follow some tutorial or course, don't believe thing's will work same way.

Number two: inside resources/assets/js/components/passport/, open each component.vue (example client.vue) and after  insert:

```
var axios = require("axios");
```